# Как сделать кнопку, которая анимируется при наведении, как кнопка, найденная на Airforce.com

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, анимация

Как сделать, чтобы кнопка анимировалась при наведении курсора точно так же, как кнопки в этом `GIF` или на [airforce.com](https://www.airforce.com/).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54605009/7394871

Answer (score 7):

Вот идея с одним элементом и `multiple background`:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 20px;
  border-right:1px solid;
  border-left:1px solid;
  background:
      linear-gradient(#000,#000) top left,
      linear-gradient(#000,#000) top right,
      linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom right,
      linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom left;
  background-size:15% 1px,75% 1px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:.8s all;
}
.box:hover {
  background-size:75% 1px,15% 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some text
</div>

<div class="box">
  more and more text
</div>
```

Если вы хотите изменить размер пробела, вы можете настроить `background-size`. Вот пример с `10px` для прозрачной части, начиная с `10px` от края.

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 20px;
  border-right:1px solid;
  border-left:1px solid;
  background:
      linear-gradient(#000,#000) top left,
      linear-gradient(#000,#000) top right,
      linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom right,
      linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom left;
  background-size:10px 1px,calc(100% - 20px) 1px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:.8s all;
}
.box:hover {
  background-size:calc(100% - 20px) 1px,10px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some text
</div>

<div class="box">
  more and more text
</div>
```

Еще одна идея с градиентом:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 20px;
  border-right:1px solid;
  border-left:1px solid;
  background:
      linear-gradient(to right,
        #000 calc(50% - 5px),transparent calc(50% - 5px),
        transparent calc(50% + 5px),#000 calc(50% + 5px)),
      linear-gradient(to right,
        #000 calc(50% - 5px),transparent calc(50% - 5px),
        transparent calc(50% + 5px),#000 calc(50% + 5px));       
  background-size:150% 1px;
  background-position:top left,bottom right;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:.8s all;
}
.box:hover {
  background-position:top right,bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some text
</div>

<div class="box">
  more and more text
</div>
```

Comment: Класс! Я уже даже знаю где такое прикреплю:))))

Comment: Там на сайте (источнике), есть ещё такой же похожий блок (по принципу работы), только круглый. Тоже привлекает внимание.

Comment: @L.F.C. да, я видел, две полусферы крутятся, кстати сделать не сложно, сейчас попробую

Comment: @L.F.C. готов [ответ по вращению окружности с двумя вырезами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/943685/28748)

Answer (score 4):

Пробовал анимировать границы, но это было очень сложно, поэтому просто сделал `:: after` и `:: before` для кнопки, а затем анимировал ее.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 93vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #222;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.brk-btn {
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  color: aqua;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0.2em solid aqua;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

.brk-btn::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  background: #222;
  height: 0.3em;
  right: 20%;
  top: -0.21em;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
}

.brk-btn::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  background: #222;
  height: 0.3em;
  left: 20%;
  bottom: -0.25em;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45 cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
}

.brk-btn:hover::before {
  right: 80%;
}

.brk-btn:hover::after {
  left: 80%;
}

.underlined-a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aqua;
  padding-bottom: 0.15em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -0.2em 0 aqua;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.underlined-a:hover {
  color: #222;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2em 0 aqua;
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
}
```

```html
<div>As inspired from the website of the <a href="https://www.airforce.com/" class="underlined-a">&nbsp;U.S. AirForce&nbsp;</a></div>
<br><br>
<a href="https://www.airforce.com/" class="brk-btn">
  Join Now
</a>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54605068/7394871): @Your Pal Nurav